# standalone Ruby script to Rails 4 web app: where to store configuration details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At work we have a downloadable ZIP file and on the download page we list the contents of the file so that people know what the ZIP contains.  Before, this list of ZIP contents was manually maintained and it was often inaccurate/out of date.  To fix this problem, I wrote a standalone Ruby script that is called from the command line like `$ ruby my_script.rb arg1 arg2 arg3`. This script generates the HTML that we can paste into the web page to display the ZIP file contents.

`arg1` is the path to the extracted contents of the ZIP file, and `arg2` and `arg3` are paths to CSV files that contain data like so:

```
#arg2 — version numbers
/path/to/some/file,4.0
/path/to/another/file,3.2.9
/path/to/third/file,1.0

#arg3 — descriptions
/path/to/fourth/file,Here is a description
/path/to/fifth/file,Here is a description
/path/to/sixth/file,Here is a description
```

I want to convert this standalone Ruby script to a Rails 4 web app so that multiple people within the company can generate the needed HTML.

My question is where should I be storing the data that `arg2` and `arg3` contain?  Both of these files need to be able to be updated by whomever is generating the HTML.  I thought maybe I could store this info in the DB, one DB record per line of the CSV, and then provide an interface for adding/deleting/updating the records.  Then to get the data I would use Version.all or Description.all to get all of the records.  I am a bit hesitant, though, to make a model to hold this data since it doesn't really model anything—it is just a saveable representation of a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

The data is the relatively simple part - you should keep it in your models & database.

You'll likely want two models (`User` and `Details`), which you'll be able to populate with the following code:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :details
end

#app/models/detail.rb
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | version | description | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
end
```

You can use [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, giving you the ability to accept registration & population of users in your app. You'll then be able to associate the `details` of your app with each of the users you have.

You'll be able to get this working relatively simply:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :details do
    get :send #-> domain.com/details/:detail_id/send
end

#app/controllers/details_controller.rb
class DetailsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def new
      @detail = current_user.details.new
   end

   def create
     @detail = current_user.details.new details_params
     @detail.save
   end

   def send
       #invoke rake task here
   end

   private 

   def details_params
      params.require(:detail).permit(:user_id, :version, :description)
   end
end
```

Finally, this will give you the ability to [use `Rake`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake) like this:

```
#lib/tasks/file.rake
namespace :file do
    task :send => :environment do
        #invoke script for file here
    end
end
```

--

Obviously this is supremely generalised, but hopefully it will give you the ability to see how you *can* integrate a standalone Ruby script into a Rails app.

IMO, Rails should really be used to give you the ability to manage users & data in a more structured way. Coming from Ruby / native dev, you'll understand that Rails is just a framework (indeed, "just" [a gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails)), which will give you the ability to manage your data more coherently. It will not replicate or replace your native / back-end code